Can a trained RL network outperforms the best training sample?
I'm working on solving a problem where I need to determine the optimal set of actions to find the path that yields the maximum reward. I'm currently using a Deep Q-Network (DQN) for this task. However, the performance of the trained network only matches, at best, the best path found during the training. In some cases, the trained network cannot even match the best path if the best paths only appear a few times.
Are there any strategies or adjustments I can make to train a network that can outperform the best path discovered during exploration?

there are several updates to the vanilla DQN that improve performance, if you google the RAINBOW paper they are mostly listed there.
